# Multiple background tcpdump processes inside docker

Tags: docker, tcpdump

I am developing a system using microservices in docker where I want to analyze the network traffic of different docker containers running inside a given docker network.

Right now I have a container running supervisord and connected to the host network to access the host's interface, like this:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian
ENV PCAP_READ_DIR '/data'
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y -q install \
    tcpdump supervisor && \
    apt-get clean
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

supervisord.conf:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:init_script]
command=/app/init.sh
numprocs=1
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
redirect_stderr: true
autorestart: false
startretries=0
```

And my init.sh script will eventually run a variable number of tcpdump processes in the background.

init.sh:

```
...etc..

while :
do
  info "Watch the wlp3s0 interface"

  tcpdump -s 0 -c 10 -w "data/pcap/default_br-1234_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.pcap"

  sleep 3
done
```

The container executes properly and with tcpdump even running in foreground, the pcap's are generated but there is no data reflecting the network traffic happening on the host (visiting a given website for example).

[EDIT]: This is the command I execute to run the docker container:

```
docker run --rm -it \
       -v "$PWD":/app \
       -v "$PWD"/data:/app/data \
       -v "$PWD"/supervisord.conf:/etc/supervisord.conf \
       -p 1234:80 \
       --network host \
       --name docker-watcher \
       -e MODE=development \
       docker-watcher
```

Comment: try adding `--privileged` to your `docker run` command

Comment: I had to overcome an error by adding in the Dockerfile: ```RUN mv /usr/sbin/tcpdump /usr/bin/tcpdump``` but yet it seems now that if I wait long enough it only captures some of the http traffic.

Comment: Did you manage to get something logged? I tried to do a tcpdump of a dockerized mysql container using the crccheck/tcpdump docker image, where i needed to add `-i any` option to the tcpdump command. Probably also try `-i all` or similar. Also: Do you see tcpdump's output somewhere - it could provide some hints.

Comment: I managed to get the logged output of the tcpdump process by calling it from the supervisord application, as I did here in an old project: https://github.com/big-data-europe/mu-docker-watcher-service